# Selecting drop down option using XPath - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, xpath

I want to choose an item from the Drop Down. But on compiling, it is unable to find the element.

```
<select name="ctl00$cphmain$ddlWorkstation" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$cphmain$ddlWorkstation\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_cphmain_ddlWorkstation" class="dropdown_s" style="width:180px;">
<option value="Select" title="Select">Select</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2" title="Hospital A">Hospital A</option>
</select>
```

The code I have written is:

```
IWebElement facilityName = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@name='ctl00$cphmain$ddlWorkstation']"));
SelectElement select = new SelectElement(facilityName);
select.SelectByText("Hospital A");
```

The error I am facing:

```
Test method ChromeProject.Login.Chrome_Login threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@name='ctl00$cphmain$ddlWorkstation']"}
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem that you're trying to handle dynamic element. You might need to wait some time until `select` present in `DOM`:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
IWebElement facilityName = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(By.XPath("//select[@name='ctl00$cphmain$ddlWorkstation']")));
SelectElement select = new SelectElement(facilityName);
select.SelectByText("Hospital A");
```